# How do I select previous row in active record query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, redmine

I am new to Rails and making a plugin for Redmine as my first project. I need to find how much time passed between status changes in issues.

I calculate this by doing the following for each status change:

- From creation date, subtract the previous status change's creation date
- If it is the first status change on the issue, subtract the issue's creation date.

I wrote the following code in PostgreSQL using `lag` function to access previous row, which gives me the desired output.

```
SELECT issues.subject, journals.id,
COALESCE(
(journals.created_on - lag(journals.created_on) 
 OVER (PARTITION BY journals.journalized_id ORDER BY journals.created_on)),
journals.created_on - issues.created_on
) AS time_elapsed
FROM journals 
INNER JOIN journal_details ON journal_details.journal_id = journals.id
INNER JOIN issues ON issues.id = journals.journalized_id 
WHERE journal_details.prop_key = 'status_id';
```

...and in Rails I did...

```
Journal.joins(:details, :issue)
.where(:journal_details => {prop_key: :status_id})
.select("issues.subject, journals.id")
```

However, in order to select the previous row I can't use the Postgres' functions because I need this code to be database agnostic.

Messing around for hours, I could only come up with the idea of a subquery that selects the previous row:

```
subquery = "SELECT j.created_on FROM journals AS j 
INNER JOIN journal_details ON journal_details.journal_id = j.id 
WHERE journal_details.prop_key = 'status_id' 
AND j.journalized_id = journals.journalized_id 
AND j.id < journals.id ORDER BY j.id DESC LIMIT 1"

Journal.joins(:details, :issue)
.where(:journal_details => {prop_key: :status_id})
.select("issues.subject, journals.id, 
COALESCE(journals.created_on - (#{subquery}), 
(journals.created_on - issues.created_on)) AS time_elapsed")
```

This is not a viable option as it performs one more select query for each row and I need a performance effective solution. (also not DRY.)

So my question is, how can I use active record query interface (if I can, of course) to select previous row? Or at least, what would be the best practice/rails way solution this problem?

Comment: "in order to select the previous row I can't use the Postgres' functions because I need this code to be database agnostic. " function `LAG()` also works in the most populair DBMS like MySQL 8.0. Oracle 10g Release 2 (10.2)+ (i believe can be earler), PostgreSQL 8.4+, SQL Server(MSSQL) version 2012+, SQLite looks to me using `LAG()` it's pretty database agnostic

Comment: Besides if you are worring about database agnostic.. `LIMIT` only works in MySQL, MariaDB (fork of MySQL) and PostgreSQL. So you should not worry about using `LAG()` not to be  database agnostic

Comment: If you know the query you want to make in SQL, you can also just do a [raw query](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-exec_query), or post a working query that you can't quite massage into ActiveRecord syntax as that might get more targeted help. You might also consider asking SQL-specific (as opposed to ORM) questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I'm overlooking some complexity here, but it seems the simplest solution would be just to track the previous record in rails?

```
previous_detail = nil

journal.journal_details.each do |detail|
  if previous_detail
    # do processing with current and prevous details
  else
    # do progessing with current detail and journal
  end
  previous_detail = detail
end
```

Comment: I tried this in my first attempt but if I do the processing (calculation of times) in rails then I won't be able to use that result data for sorting or grouping by. I mean I could do these in application layer as well but it would be much slower. That's why I am trying to calculate it on DB side and have it as a column on the query result.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  One thought is your plugin could migrate new fields and the columns could be populated via a before_create callaback, and there's be an initial seeding to populate the new fields in the existing records, and in the end it would make the queries more performant.